# Split files for train and test in Google Colab

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I have successfully trained and tested my model on local jupyter notebook, but I want to try the same code in Google Colab as I want to try other expensive models of CNN.
Can somebody please help me what is wrong here. I have uploaded my files in the Google Colab environment from my Google Drive. Here I want to split files from 100 folders for train and test but every time I get the error that No Such File or directory.

```
folder = 'sample_data/firmasSINTESISmanuscritas'
number_of_users = 100
count_of_users = 0
for dir in os.listdir(folder):
print(dir)
filenames = [
    #os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), folder+'\\'+dir, i) for i in os.listdir(folder+'\\'+dir)
    os.path.join(folder+'\\'+dir, i) for i in os.listdir(folder+'\\'+dir)
]
filenames = filenames[:-1]

labels = [filename.__contains__('c-') for filename in filenames]
labels = np.array(labels, dtype=bool).astype(int).tolist()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(filenames, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

filenames_train = filenames_train + x_train
filenames_test = filenames_test + x_test
Y_train = Y_train + y_train
Y_test = Y_test + y_test

count_of_users += 1
if number_of_users <= count_of_users:
    break
print('end')

[Error][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already mounted your google drive to colab to access those files? if not, please do so by following the commands mentioned in  [this blog post](https://medium.com/@uditsaini/access-google-drive-and-mount-google-drive-to-colab-notebook-google-ccbca1691d31).

Comment: Yes I have mounted it already and my data set is downloaded from drive to work space.

Comment: Can you share your directory structure in the colab?